A question about Nagata's proof
I'm reading "The red book of varieties and Schemes" by D Mumford, and there is the proof of Noether's Normalization Lemma.(page 2)
In the proof, we pick the $r_i$'s to be large enough, and increasing rapidly enough:
\begin{equation}
0 \ll r_2 \ll \ldots \ll r_m
\end{equation}
But I think that there's no need to assume that they increase rapidly, we just need $r_i$'s to be large enough:
\begin{equation}
0 \ll r_2, \ldots, r_m
\end{equation}
But why do we need the assumption?

Why do you say "Nagata's proof" in the title? Maybe you have a good reason, but it's confusing for readers...

I'm sorry you are right, this title makes people confused and I also know this post is not good because people don't have "the read book..." can't understand the background of this proof... especially what $r_i$'s imply. \ The reason I used "Nagata's proof" in the title is just the author wrote his name in the beginning of the proof, like Proof(Nagata). Thus I thought the way of this proof is given by him.

To improve the post, please add more context, like the details of the proof you're asking about.

@T.Sen If you agree then change the title so that it's more helpful for current and future readers.

Change the title to a more appropriate one, and add more details for better context. Would prefer you to not be in trouble over something you can fix almost easily.

The point is that each term $a\cdot\prod_{i=1}^my_i^{b_i}$ in $f(y_1,\dots,y_m)$ gives a term $a\cdot y_1^{b_1+r_2b_2+\cdots+r_mb_m}$ in $f(y_1,z_2+y_1^{r_2},\dots, z_m+y_1^{r_m})$, and one of them becomes the unique highest order term.
For example if $f(y_1,y_2,y_3)=y_1+y_2+y_3$ then
$$f(y_1,z_2+y_1^{r_2},z_3+y_1^{r_3})=y_1^{r_2}+y_1^{r_3}+(y_1+z_2+z_3).$$
Thus, to insure there is a unique highest order term, it does not suffice to let $r_3,r_2\gg0$, for if $r_2=r_3$ then $y_1^{r_2}$ and $y_1^{r_3}$ are both highest degree terms.
